# Increasing Java Heap Size on Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, heap-size

Does anyone know how to increase Java heap size one Neo4j?

I'm loading a csv file into Neo4j Database and I can't load it because I need to increase Java Heap Size...
I checked that I have more than 100GB free... I also have 16Gb of RAM.
My Jar file is located in "C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.1.4\bin\neo4j-desktop-3.1.4.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the neo4j.conf, which is located in `C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.1.4\conf\` by uncommenting and settings these lines:

```
# Java Heap Size: by default the Java heap size is dynamically
# calculated based on available system resources.
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size.
#dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=512m
#dbms.memory.heap.max_size=512m

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, in bytes (or
# kilobytes with the 'k' suffix, megabytes with 'm' and gigabytes with 'g').
# If Neo4j is running on a dedicated server, then it is generally recommended
# to leave about 2-4 gigabytes for the operating system, give the JVM enough
# heap to hold all your transaction state and query context, and then leave the
# rest for the page cache.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 50% of RAM minus the max Java heap size.
#dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g
```

Know that if you are using `LOAD CSV` functionality, you can batch your transaction with `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` prefix. Example from the [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV FROM 'https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/csv/artists.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInt(line[2])})
```